# Как передать событие клика с одного элемента на другой?

Tags: jquery, css, select

Это что-то наподобие `jquery selectbox`. Для позиционирования `div`, заменяющего `select`, использовал `offset()`. Измеряю ширину и высоту селектов. В результате `div`-ы нормально отображаются. Но проблема в том, что дивы оказались выше селектов. А опустить их ниже я не могу. При `z-index: -1;` они уходят за контент. Как передать клик от дива к селекту?

Вот код:

```
// click send to replacer
$('select').click(function(e) {
  $(this).next('.sel-wrapper').trigger('click'); // это не работает
});

$('select').each(function(index, element) {
  var realSelect = $(this);
  if(!(realSelect.next('.sel-wrapper').length)){
  realSelect.after('<div class="sel-wrapper"><div class="sel-body"></div><div class="sel-btn"></div></div>');
}
// dimensions
var selWrapper = realSelect.next('.sel-wrapper');
selWrapper.width(realSelect.width());
selWrapper.height(realSelect.height());
selWrapper.css({'border':'1px solid violet'});

// position
var selectPos = realSelect.offset();
selWrapper.offset({top: selectPos.top, left: selectPos.left});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Триггером - [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Посмотрите код. Триггер там уже есть. Он не работает. И с кавычками и без.

Comment: $(this).next('.sel-wrapper').length// Если это возвращает ненулевое значение(в чем я сомневаюсь), то уж обработку события "клик" на sel-wrapper я уже точно в коде не вижу.

И, кстати. Когда будете писать обработчик, напишите его с использованием live(старая jquery) или on(новая).